# Using variables in query don't get result. Real values do. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select

Stored procedure with 3 variables does a `select` with them.
No result.

Changing the variables to literal values does get result.
Why?

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_Code_Dossier] FROM [nchar](6) NOT NULL
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_Code_Detail] FROM [nchar](3) NOT NULL
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_Code_DetailSub] FROM [nchar](3) NOT NULL
```

```sql
declare 
   @DossierCode T_Code_Dossier = 779,
   @DetailCode T_Code_Detail = 10,
   @DetailSubCode T_Code_DetailSub = 0
```

```sql
SELECT
   t1.PartCode,
   t1.SalesUnitType,
   t1.CalcQty,
   t1.Length,
   t1.Width,
   t1.Height,
   t1.SalesUnitOfAccount
FROM dbo.T_DossierDetail  AS t1
WHERE
   t1.DossierCode = @DossierCode AND 
   t1.DetailCode = @DetailCode AND 
   t1.DetailSubCode = @DetailSubCode
```

No result.

```sql
SELECT
   t1.PartCode,
   t1.SalesUnitType,
   t1.CalcQty,
   t1.Length,
   t1.Width,
   t1.Height,
   t1.SalesUnitOfAccount
FROM dbo.T_DossierDetail  AS t1
WHERE
   t1.DossierCode = 779 AND 
   t1.DetailCode = 10 AND 
   t1.DetailSubCode = 0
```

1 result.

Why?

Comment: How are you executing procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mainly due to your data & the `No Result` query. By using string data type to store numeric value, you might end up with possible `0___` or `_0_` or even `__0`

so your query `WHERE` clause for `t1.DetailSubCode  = @DetailSubCode` might not get any matches.

However, using `t1.DetailSubCode = 0` forces the value in table `DetailSubCode` to perform an implicit conversion to integer before comparison. So this case, All these values `0___` or `_0_` or even `__0` gets converted to numeric `0` and compare and it matches

execute the following query and see the difference

```
declare @tbl table
(
    id  int identity,
    col1    nchar(3)
)

insert into @tbl select '0'
insert into @tbl select ' 0'
insert into @tbl select '  0'

declare @v nchar(3) = 0

-- your first only. Only 1 row return
select  *
from    @tbl
where   col1 = @v

-- your second query. All 3 rows return
select  *
from    @tbl
where   col1 = 0
```

Reference : [Data Type Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    declare 
   @DossierCode int = 779,
   @DetailCode int = 10,
   @DetailSubCode int = 0


      SELECT
         t1.PartCode,
         t1.SalesUnitType,
         t1.CalcQty,
         t1.Length,
         t1.Width,
         t1.Height,
         t1.SalesUnitOfAccount
      FROM dbo.T_DossierDetail  AS t1
      WHERE
      t1.DossierCode = @DossierCode AND 
      t1.DetailCode = @DetailCode AND 
      t1.DetailSubCode = @DetailSubCode
```

If this works, then possible reason is in your query you are passing `int` value to the fields in where clause, while in procedure you declare your variable with custom data type. There might be chance of mismatching in this.

**Edit**

SQL Server has far too much of implicit conversions.
I recommend that you always use explicit conversion between strings and numbers to make your code clearer.

Comment: Yes. It works. But why?  T_Code_Dossier is a nchar (6). Same type as t1.Dossiercode

Comment: are you sure please check your table schema again.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Creating a create script for this table:  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_DossierDetail](
 [DossierCode] [dbo].[T_Code_Dossier] NOT NULL,
 [DetailCode] [dbo].[T_Code_Detail] NOT NULL,
 [DetailSubCode] [dbo].[T_Code_DetailSub] NOT NULL,

Comment: @saho We can't create that script because we don't have the definition for [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-user-defined-data-type-alias?view=sql-server-2017) `T_Code_Dossier`, `T_Code_Detail` and `T_Code_DetailSub`. You should add them to your question.

Comment: CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_Code_Dossier] FROM [nchar](6) NOT NULL   is the createcode for the t_Code_dossier. The others are them same with nchar(3)

Comment: and what about the other 2 types `T_Code_Detail ' and `T_Code_DetailSub `

Comment: CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_Code_Detail] FROM [nchar](3) NOT NULL
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_Code_DetailSub] FROM [nchar](3) NOT NULL